# Array of instances of a library in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

How can I construct array of instances of a kind of library (lets say `Student`) after loading it in CodeIgniter? As far as I know after loading `student` library using `$this->load->library('student');`  I can access single `student` using `$this->student`   . Here is my question, I need an array of this `student`s how can I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really use a model instead of a library. **Libraries** are used to extend the functionality of CodeIgniter. **Models** let you interact with your data; Students in this case. Using a library to get your data and instantiating it is shooting yourself in the foot.

In your `Student_model`, you can put functions that grab your data (from a database or wherever):

```
function get_students() {
    // Returns an array or object of all students and their info
}

function get($student_id) {
    // Returns a single student's information
}

// Additional CRUD functions, if desired.
```

Additionally, I recommend having another look at:

- http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/overview/mvc.html
- http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: -1 for: my question was simply "Array of instances of a library". where did you get that 'student' is grabbing info from database.
-1 for: as u stated " // Returns an array or object of all students and their info" I am asking for how can I construct array of objects.

Comment: Libraries are not meant to be instantiated. What you are trying to do involves models - regardless of whether you are using databases. I was providing constructive feedback based on your innovative approach to using CodeIgniter. If you are unable to accept suggestions and criticism, I would recommend visiting other websites. Good luck.

Comment: thank you "Libraries are not meant to be instantiated." was the answer I was expecting, the rest is maybe someone else's unability to be critisized.

Answer (score 1):

inside your library file

```
 function get_student_list()
 {
      // $uqery = SQL query to get the students - or a call to your model to get them

      return $query;
 }
```

then in your controller

```
 $list = $this->student->get_student_list();
```

Comment: your solution tells me that my student library should contain list in itself. but I need a list which contains students.

Comment: so where is your student list stored? and i'm not saying the library stores the list - im saying you create a function in the library, which collects the list, and returns it to your other controller

Comment: I will store and use my list in a controller. I want it to be like $p =array($student1,$student2,$student3);

I got what u mean, I will try it as a last shot.